# Usage of the word "Happen" or Happens"?

Tags: meaning

"*Everybody has an addiction ,Mine just **happens** to be you*" in this sentence can anyone tell me how "happens" is used? and other usage of word "happens"?

Comment: It [happens to be](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/happen) idiomatic.

Comment: _Happen_ is what is called an [Implicative verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf); it takes a subject complement, usually extraposed, leaving a dummy _it_ behind. _Happen_ can optionally govern Subject-Raising instead of Extraposition. That's the case with the example. It comes from _For my addiction to be you just happens_, which is hopelessly awkward if not ungrammatical, so obligatory Subject-Raising --> _My addiction just happens to be you_ and then conjunction-reduction deletes _addiction_ and changes _my_ to _mine_.

Comment: Next week,  John Lawler will give Fermat's own proof of the Last Theorem. In a 'comment'.

Comment: It's not conjunction reduction, it's indefinite pronominalization: my addiction -> my one -> mine.

Answer (score 1):

"X happens to be Y" is an idiomatic way of saying "**X is Y**" that suggests **happy chance or good luck**.

From [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/happen):

> 2. To have the fortune (to be or do something); be in a situation or position (to be or do something): *The bus station happens to be close to the museum. I happen to know the answer to that question.*